# JQuery Conditional statement not working

Tags: jquery, loops, conditional-statements, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
row[1] = false;
row[2] = false;
row[3] = false;
row[4] = false;
row[5] = false;
row[6] = false;
$('.row1bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row2bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row3bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row4bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row5bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row6bback').fadeOut(0);
function rowrfade() {
    var rRow = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    var rDelay = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20)) * 1000;
    rowfade(rRow, rDelay);
}
function rowfade(rRow, rDelay) {
  if (row[rRow] == false || row[rRow] == "") {
      $('.row'+ rRow + 'aback').delay(rDelay).fadeOut(10000);
      $('.row'+ rRow + 'bback').delay(rDelay).fadeIn(10000);
      return row[rRow] = true;
      rowrfade();
  } else if (row[rRow] == true) {
      $('.row'+ rRow + 'aback').delay(rDelay).fadeIn(10000);
      $('.row'+ rRow + 'bback').delay(rDelay).fadeOut(10000);
      return row[rRow] = false;
      rowrfade();
  }
}
    //row1fade();
    rowrfade();
});
```

I am trying to randomly hide/show 1 of 2 pictures for 6 rows. I am trying to understand what the best way is to make this function work.

I would like to check which picture is shown for the random row called. If it is picture a (value = false) or picture b (value = true). If picture a is shown, then fadeout picture a and show picture b for that row. This cycle will continually repeat and loop.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="mframe">
  <div class="row1aback">
  </div>
  <div class="row1bback">
  </div>
  <div class="row2aback">
  </div>
  <div class="row2bback">
  </div>
  <div class="row3aback">
  </div>
  <div class="row3bback">
  </div>
  <div class="row4aback">
  </div>
  <div class="row4bback">
  </div>
  <div class="row5aback">
  </div>
  <div class="row5bback">
  </div>
  <div class="row6aback">
  </div>
  <div class="row6bback">
  </div>
</div>
```

My Images are using the background image css property. I also only have a total of 6 rows with 2 images per row. By default I show the first image and hide the second one using JS. Then I randomly pick a row and a random delay between 1 and 20 seconds. I then use this to change the picture in the random picked row. I use the delay to make the effect appear to happen randomly.

I have since changed my code and am using the following condition statement to get this function to work. Let me know if you know of another way of making it work.

Thanks.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.row1bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row2bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row3bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row4bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row5bback').fadeOut(0);
$('.row6bback').fadeOut(0);
function rowrfade() {
    var rRow = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    var rDelay = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)) * 1000;
    var fTimer = 6500;
    rstatus = $('.row' + rRow + 'aback').css('display');
    if (rstatus == 'block') {
        $('.row'+ rRow + 'aback').delay(rDelay).fadeOut(fTimer);
        $('.row'+ rRow + 'bback').delay(rDelay).fadeIn(fTimer, 
        function() {
            rowrfade()
        });
    } else if (rstatus == 'none') {
        $('.row'+ rRow + 'aback').delay(rDelay).fadeIn(fTimer);
        $('.row'+ rRow + 'bback').delay(rDelay).fadeOut(fTimer, 
        function() {
            rowrfade()
        });
    }
}
rowrfade();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the fadeIn and fadeOut callbacks to make this work properly so that an item does not start to fade in before the next item starts to fade out.

Storing an array in that way is not very scalable. In my example I store all the rows in an jquery object and just keep track of the current row.

Since you only have two picture I have hidden one of the children and then work out which one to fade in or out based on whether it is visible or not. If you were to use more than two items you would have to tweak this.

I hope this helps.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var current = 0;
    var $rows = $('.row');

    $rows.each(function() {
        $(this).children(':last').hide();
    });

    function fade() {
        var newRow = null;
        do {
            newRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * $rows.length);
        } while(newRow === current);    

        var $row = $rows.eq(current);
        var $hide = $row.children(':visible');
        var $show = $row.children(':not(:visible)');

        $hide.fadeOut('slow');
        $show.fadeIn('slow', function() {
            current = newRow;
            fade();
        });
    }

    fade();
});

</script>
<div class="row">1: <span>A</span><span>B</span></div>
<div class="row">2: <span>A</span><span>B</span></div>
<div class="row">3: <span>A</span><span>B</span></div>
<div class="row">4: <span>A</span><span>B</span></div>
<div class="row">5: <span>A</span><span>B</span></div>
<div class="row">6: <span>A</span><span>B</span></div>
</html>
```

Comment: I am on purpose fading an image out while one is fading in. This is to create a picture dissolving into another picture at the same time.

Comment: Well then you just move the fadeIn below the callback.

Though you probably want to keep the recursive call inside the callback so it doesn't start another row until that fade in is done.

You will also need to work out how to get the positioning right so that they sit on top of each other.

Comment: I updated my text below. For each row, I am trying to fade between two images. Your code will fade through all 6 images one at a time. I need to check the status of which image is displayed per row and then perform a fade based upon this.